# The imported project "Xamarin.iOS.CSharp.targets" was not found error - Visual Studio 7 - Mac

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios, mono, visual-studio-mac

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms project with Visual Studio 2017 Professional with Windows machine. Also, I am using a Mac to build and run the iOS app by pairing the Mac with VS 2017. Sometimes Visual Studio on Mac is also used to build and run the app for both iOS and Android platforms of the same project and Macbook had Visual Studio 2017 for Mac.

Recently I had to restore the Macbook and reinstall the Xamarin development setup. Now the problem is if I install VS 2019 for Mac, it comes with Mono version 6.x.x and my VS 2017 on windows doesn't support that version as it always tells that there's a "Mono version mismatch" and asks to install Mono version 5.18.1, but VS 2019 for Mac does not support that version.

Then I downloaded VS 2017 for mac from the archive and did a fresh installation. After that, when I tried to pair mac with VS on Windows machine, it again notified the "Mono version mismatch" and installed mono 5.18.1. With that version, even a simple Xamarin.Forms project could not able to build on VS 2017 on Mac as it reports this error:

`Getting restore information for project /Projects/Hello/Hello.iOS/Hello.iOS.csproj`
`/Projects/Hello/Hello.iOS/Hello.iOS.csproj(153,3) : error MSB4019: The imported project "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.18.1/lib/mono/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.`
`Unable to create package spec for project. /Projects/Hello/Hello.iOS/Hello.iOS.csproj`

Comment: Is your VS 2017 for window the latest? Try to update it. Also try to reinstall Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: Yes, it has the latest update for VS 2017. I tried reinstalling Xamarin.iOS, but didn't help. I think I might have to update VS on both platforms to 2019

Comment: What is the full version of Mono being used and what is the full VS Mac version? There was a change around Mono 5.18.1.24 to support later .NET Core sdks and a later MSBuild. The error you are seeing looks like a mismatch between the VS Mac v7 version and Mono's MSBuild - https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/14875#issuecomment-499998067

Comment: @MattWard yes the error comes because of a mismatch between the two VS versions. VS 2019 for Mac requires mono 6 or later, while VS 2017 on Windows requires exactly mono 5.18.1.28. So currently I keep Mono 5.18.1 in mac as it is to work on windows without any problem.

Comment: However, a Xamarin team member answered this exact question in this thread (https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/390475#Comment_390475). The most possible solution is to update VS in both platforms to 2019 the latest.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT As I have looked, when I installed VS 2017 for mac, it comes with Mono 5.16.1 as I remember. So I think it doesn't support mono 5.18.1, and I can't update the Mac's VS 2017 to a specific update which supports mono 5.18.1.

Comment: Yep, try to use the latest version on both side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best solution, but updating Visual Studio on both platforms to 2019 solved the issue.